# Get the sum value from sum_other_doc_count in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Get the sum value from sum_other_doc_count in elasticsearch

I have a bunch of documents like this:

> London -> 5 students
>   London -> 7 students
>   London -> 3 students
>   Barcelona -> 1 students
>   Barcelona -> 12 students
>   ...

I perform a query with an aggregation **terms by CITY** and another aggretation **sum by STUDENTS**

The result is list of: key(city), doc_count and students(sum)

Is there a way to get the the sum value of students from the **sum_other_doc_count**?
I'm not interested on the num of docs but the sum of the other cities students.

Query:

```
"aggs" = {
    "city" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "city",
            "order": {
                "sum_students": "desc"
            }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "sum_students" : {
                "sum" : {
                    "field" : "students"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "buckets": [{
        "sum_students": {
            "value": 942045
        },
        "key": "London",
        "doc_count": 4645
    }, {
        "sum_students": {
            "value": 676932
        },
        "key": "Barcelona",
        "doc_count": 3831
    }],
    "sum_other_doc_count": 19992,
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe a naive approach would be to get the total student through a global sum aggregation and subtract the sum_students from you buckets